# How to pass a button action from a uiview to another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a uiview named leftMenuView and on that view i have a button and i want to add an action to that button so that action method should call a view controller. Take a look what till i have done:

this is my leftMenuView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class LeftMenuView;

@protocol LeftMenuViewProtocol <NSObject>

-(void)homeClicked;

@end

@interface LeftMenuView : UIView

@property (nonatomic,assign) id<LeftMenuViewProtocol> customDelegate;

-(IBAction)homeClickedAction:(id)sender;

@end
```

and in leftMenuView.m file

```
#import "LeftMenuView.h"

@implementation LeftMenuView

-(IBAction)homeClickedAction:(id)sender
{
  [self.customDelegate homeClicked];

  NSLog(@"Clicked Home");
}

@end
```

Now i am trying to call that method through the delegate

Now in homeViewController.h

```
@interface homeViewController : UIViewController<LeftMenuViewProtocol>
```

and now in my homeViewController.m i am trying to call that method but it is not called

```
-(void)homeClicked

{

  NSLog(@"Clicked Home");

}
```

But the above method is not called where as in leftViewMenu.m that method is called. Hope any one helps me regarding this issue.

Comment: Did you set your `customDelegate` (something like `leftView.customDelegate = self;` in the `viewDidload` of your `homeViewController`) ?

Comment: I can´t image how you have managed to connect and IBAction button with a view class.

Comment: Yes as Bonafons says above, you didnt mention whether you have set the the homeviewcontroller as a delegate to the leftViewMenu class. You have just mentioned that homeViewController is confirming to the LeftMenuViewProtocol

Comment: i have written leftView.customDelegate = self; but still no progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or, assuming you have a reference on your `leftMenuView` in your `homeViewController` you can create your `UIButton` programmatically and set the target of your button with your `homeViewController`. For example, in the viewDidLoad of your `homeViewController`, you can do something like:

```
UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20)]; // set the frame you want 
myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // Do additional set up
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(homeClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; // here the target of your button's action is your homeViewController
[self.leftMenuView addSubView:myButton]; // Add the button in your left view
```

Comment: Simple answer but very effective.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in **homeViewController** you have a property for the **LeftMenuView** you need to set the **customDelegate** to **self**. In the **homeViewController** *viewDidLoad* method:

```
self.leftMenuView.customDelegate = self;
```